# JSON, cellForRowAtIndexPath bug

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

Struggling to find where fault is with my code. On first view load, everything works and loads fine as it should, but when i revisit that view, it seems that the first two cells are empty. I logged the dictionary (dict) in `viewWillAppear:` and it logs the data fine, so error has to be in `cellForRow` method. Take a look at my method, and see where i'm going wrong, the third cell populate third piece of data, so i'm totally stumped, but the first two cells are completely blank, no data.

http://pastebin.com/Va84MG5g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why are you doing all of that insane `UITableViewCell` customization inside of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? Create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and do the set up there.

In the class's `initWithStyle:` method, add all of your subviews with a frame of `CGRectZero`, because at initialization, the table view cell doesn't know how big it is. You can set text alignments, colors, etc. here as well. Then, in `layoutSubviews`, go ahead and set all the frames. Override `prepareForReuse` and set things like your `UIImageViews` to nil. This will help with performance for reused cells.

As for why you're not seeing your data in your first two cells, my initial thought is that it has something to do with the way you're setting up your cells for reuse. You're asking your tableView to dequeue a regular `UITableViewCell` and only creating all of these subviews if the returned cell is `nil`. So what happens when it returns a `UITableViewCell`? You skip the part where you alloc/init all these subviews, and so you're basically adding nothing to the cell. I feel if you create a custom subclass and ask your `UITableView` to dequeue **that** instead, you'll get the result you're looking for.

**NOTE:** If you're targeting at least iOS 5, you can create your `UITableViewCell`'s layout in a nib and register the nib with the table view. Doing so will guarantee that you always get a dequeued cell, and you never have to do your if (cell == nil) check. If you're targeting iOS 6, you can register a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: I am a newbie, thanks for your help! Don't have much idea how to do much of this, could you show me some sample code, help much appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: Hey sorry I wasn't around to show sample code but I'm glad you got it sorted.